# List Button is not passing parameter in URL for a particular profile

Tags: custom-button, profile, list, url, parameters

I have a list button on a related list of custom Object ABC under Contact object which redirects to a VF page (custom record creation page for ABC). I am passing contact id in the URL so that contact's id can be defaulted in ABC record creation page.

Code for custom button is

```
/apex/ZTS_EU_PAP?mode=new&contactId={!Contact.Id}
```

When System Admin is clicking on the list button, the URL carrying the contactId. for example

```
https://<your domain>.visual.force.com/apex/ZTS_EU_PAP?mode=new&contactId=0032A000035x0Bq
```

When an user of a custom profile is clicking on the button, no contactId is being passed. Like below -

```
https://<your domain>.visual.force.com/apex/ZTS_EU_PAP?mode=new
```

Please help me what is going wrong here.

Comment: Does the custom profile have access to the ContactId field? Lack of access could cause this. Also, please post the code that generates the URL so we can take a better look.